# Signing a message which includes another signature

Tags: solidity, signature, encryption, encoding, verification

I'm trying to implement a commit-reveal scheme, where I also want to sign the input parameters to the Solidity function which commits the encrypted message. The signature verification of the input parameters work, but the signature verification of the parameter which is the signature used for committing the encrypted data fails. Is it not possible to recover the signer from the "double-signed" signature, or what am I doing wrong? I am using the same approach to recover the signer for both signatures. The signer of both is the same. I'm using the typical signature splitting into `v`, `r` and `s` with the `ecrecover`.

Comment: Can you share the code?